# Do next method once this one is complete

Tags: jquery

I want an html element to be removed AFTER it is finished sliding up. But the remove is executed immediately.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(':button').on('click', function() {
    $("body").prepend("<div class='messageBox'>dsds</div>");
    $(".messageBox").text('You Wot!').slideUp(0).slideDown("slow");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".messageBox").slideUp("slow"); //WAIT TILL FINISH THEN....
      $(".messageBox").remove();
    }, 2000);

  });

});
```

```css
.messageBox {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Settings
</h1>
<h3>
bla bla bla bla
</h3>
<input type="button" value="SAVE" id="save" />
<input type="button" value="ERROR" id="saveE" />
```

Comment: Please look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) `$(".messageBox").slideUp("slow",function() {
      $(".messageBox").remove(); });`

Comment: There was even an exact duplicate for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
setTimeout(function() {

    $(".messageBox").slideUp("slow",function(){

    $(".messageBox").remove();

    })

 }, 2000);
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <style>
        .messageBox {
            
            background: blue;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
    
    <body>
        
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <h3>bla bla bla bla</h3>
        <input type="button" value="SAVE" id="save" />
        <input type="button" value="ERROR" id="saveE" />
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    
       $(document).ready(function() {
           
           $(':button').on('click', function() {
               
               $("body").prepend("<div class='messageBox'>dsds</div>");
               $(".messageBox").text('You Wot!').slideUp(0).slideDown("slow");
               
               setTimeout(function() {
                   $(".messageBox").slideUp("slow",function(){
                       $(".messageBox").remove();

                   })

               },2000);

           })
       })
       
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could have found this too I think... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084392/jquery-wait-till-end-of-slideup

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.queue()` function ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/queue/)):

```js
$(".messageBox").slideUp("slow").queue(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.remove();
    that.dequeue();
});
```

```css
.messageBox {
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageBox">box</div>
```

---

Or, as **mplungjan** mentioned, execute the remove function inside the slideUp() callback function

Comment: Why not just `$(".messageBox").slideUp("slow",function() {
      $(".messageBox").remove(); });`

Comment: Agree with your solution @mplungjan

Comment: I haven't covered the queue method yet, thanks for the pointer, I will read into it this eve.